# SSIS:Issue with data from a csv file:

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, scientific-notation

Issue with data from a CSV file: I downloaded some file in CSV with some values like this one: `1.21E+11`, when the values are too long.

If I convert to XLS/XLSX and change the field to numeric, that fixes the issue, but I want to do something automatized.

Comment: Use `awk`.....!

Comment: SSIS won't transform the value to numeric for you. Either convert it on your destination database or use a custom script task.

Comment: EzLo Do you have any  example of that script?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a derived column of type DT_R8 and use the following expression:

```
(DT_R8)[InputColumn]
```

As shown in the image below, i tested the following expression:

```
(DT_R8)"1.21E+11"
```

And the result was:

> 121000000000

[image]

Comment: That's not work proper in this case 6.10E+11 the conversion  should be this one 610300000000 but it's 610000000000

Comment: @AlfredoGarcia `6.10E+11` is equal to `610000000000`. But be aware that in Microsoft Excel, if value is stored as `610300000000` it may be visualized as `6.10E+11` and you can retrieve the initial value in Excel, but when reading this value outside of Excel you cannot retrieve the precise value.

Comment: @AlfredoGarcia `6.10E+11` means `6.10 * 10^10`

Comment: Yes you right  but I need the  numbers with precision, due to are ID or numbers that exist in my systems

Comment: The other thing is the data type come out from the file how DT_STR 50 when you convert to Float you get and error.